# Pass value from second activity to first activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass value from second activity to first. The second activity starts after first activity. I used `onActivityResult` and simple `Intent`. The code calls first activity but the `toast` not works.

SECOND ACTIVITY:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,ae.class);       
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        i.putExtra("name","name");
        startActivityForResult(i,0);
    }
}
```

FIRST ACTIVITY:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode ,int resultCode ,Intent data ) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String name =getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch(requestCode){
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you starting your second activity with this- startActivityForResult(i,0) ?

Comment: I started with simple Intent

Comment: with simple startActivity(intent) ?

Comment: yes.CODE:f=new Intent(this,content.class);startActivity(f);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From FirstActivity, start nextActivity like this-

```
startActivityForResult(intent, code);
```

then in SecondActivity, setResult()-

```
                Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  

                setResult(2,intent);  

                finish();
```

and then in FirstActivity, check code in onActivityResult(). You were not getting result because you are starting the second activity by startActivity() only. I hope this will help you surely.

Comment: @user3182141 also change to `Intent intent=getIntent()`

Comment: @Raghunandan where you are saying to change the Intent?

Comment: @amitsingh in second activity

Comment: @Raghunandan I think there is no harm in using a new Intent.

Comment: @amitsingh need not be. you don't need `new Intent()` you can use `getIntent()`. example http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12186/android-startactivityforresult-example/

Comment: @Raghunandan its not necessary to use only getIntent(), you can create new Intent also. See any example, you will find the same thing.

Comment: @amitsingh the point is when will you create a new intent when you want to use it to start a new activity. so using getIntent is fine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45545/discussion-between-amit-singh-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 1):

You just need the below in SecondActivity

```
  Intent i = getIntent();     
  i.putExtra("name","name"); 
  setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
  finish();
```

And in first activity in `onActivityResult`

```
String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
```

You need

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

in First Activity

Comment: @user3182141 coz you din't do it right. http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12186/android-startactivityforresult-example/. the suggestion is not wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` instead of `startActivity(intent)` in `FirstActivity` to load it. Then you implement the `onActivityResult()` method in your `FirstActivity` to get the data from `SecondActivity` by using the passed `Intent` in parameter.

Finally, in your `SecondActivity` make a call to `setResult()` method when it's going to `finish()`

Answer (score -1):

You are Going from Second To First. It will go into onCreate.

So :-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,ae.class);       
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        i.putExtra("name","name");
        startActivityForResult(i,0);
    }
}
FIRST ACTIVITY:
//in OnCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        String name =extras .getString("name");
    }
}
```

Comment: wrong no you need to get the data in onActivityResult. re read The "second activity starts after first activity"

Comment: It will go into onactivityresult on some result like taking a picture using camera intent or something. When you call second activity using intent, i have debugged it, it goes into oncreate and i get my extras there only

Comment: wrong onCreate is called only activity is destroyed and recreated. You mean first activity is destroyed ?

Comment: And even if you are going from second to first, you are calling intent  inten = new intent(second.this, first.class). It will still go to oncreate.

Comment: Dude i just mirrored his code and debugged it. It does not go into onactivityresult from second to first. It is going into oncreate. Retrieve the bundle there. My answer is correct. Fine downvote me